# Socket.io in server gets disconnect repeatedly while on client side doesn't

Tags: node.js, react-native, socket.io

I am going to make a private chat app like WhatsApp.
I connect to the server successfully
but the socket after several seconds gets disconnect from the server.
while on the client it doesn't disconnect.

**Server code:**

```
const app = require('express')();
const server = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
const port = 3000;

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

const onlineusers = {};
const socketid = {};

io.on('connection', cs => {

    cs.on('online', username => {
        if(username){
            onlineusers[username] = cs.id;
            socketid[cs.id] = username;
        }

        console.log("\nonline: ", onlineusers);
    });

    cs.on('disconnect', () => {

        delete onlineusers[socketid[cs.id]];

        console.log("\noffline: ", onlineusers);
    });

});

const chat = io.of("/chat");

chat.on('connection', cs => {

    cs.on('startchat', username => {
        if (username){
            chat.to('/chat#'+onlineusers[username]).emit('hey', 'I love programming');
        }
    });

});

server.listen(port, err => {
    if(err){
        console.error("Some Error: "+err);
    }else{
        console.log(`Server is running on port: ${port}`);
    }
});
```

**MY CLIENT code is by react-native and socket.io-client:**

**On line users file:**

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';
const SocketEndpoint = 'http://192.168.43.172:3000';

this.socket = io(SocketEndpoint, {
            transports: ['websocket']
        });
this.socket.on('connect', () => {

            if (this.state.username) {
                this.socket.emit("online", this.state.username);
            }

        });

 this.socket.on('connect_error', (err) => {
     Alert.alert(err);
 });

 this.socket.on('disconnect', () => {
     Alert.alert('disconnected');
 });
```

**Chat page file:**

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';
const SocketEndpoint = 'http://192.168.43.172:3000/chat';

this.socket = io(SocketEndpoint, {
                transports: ['websocket']
            });

this.socket.on('connect', () => {

            if (theirusername) {
                this.socket.emit('startchat', theirusername);
            }

            this.socket.on('hey', data => {
                alert(data);
            });

            this.socket.on('janajan', data => {
                alert(data);
            });

        });
```

I want to keep to client socket on the server until the client themselves gets the disconnect.
because here when I want to say hey it gets a disconnect and my message could pass to the client.
thank you before

Comment: So the server disconnects and closes the socket, but some how the client is still connected?

Comment: Yeah from server disconnects but from it doesn't.

Comment: because this function does not call when it gets disconnect.
 this.socket.on('disconnect', () => {
     Alert.alert('disconnected');
 });

Comment: you make a new connection for each page?  socket.io disconnect when you navigate between pages.  In my previous chat App, I was using a single Long connection instead.

Comment: Thank, could you please tell me how can I create this long connection socket.
I am using react navigation without redux and I dont know to keep one socket instance through the app.